# Custom UIView Subclass's drawRect not being called inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, drawrect

**Background:**
I have a subclass of `UITableViewCell` whose layout is defined as a prototype cell in a storyboard. One of the cell's `IBOutlets` is a subclass of `UIView` I made called `BorderedProfileImageView`. This class's `drawRect:` function is overridden as follows:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.f);
    CGFloat halfWidth = self.bounds.size.width/2;
    NSInteger radius = sqrt(pow(halfWidth, 2) + pow(halfWidth, 2)) - 8.5;
    CGContextAddArc(context,self.bounds.size.width/2,self.bounds.size.height/2,radius,0,2*3.1415926535898,1);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

This adds a blue ring to the UIView.

**Problem:**
The blue ring never appears, and `BorderdProfileImageView`'s `drawRect:` function never gets called. The cell still draws, the `UIImageView` which is inside the `BorderdProfileImageView` gets drawn. I do call `setNeedsDisplay` on the `BorderedProfileImageView` when setting up the cell.

Why is `drawRect:` not getting called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The object in IB which was set to the `BorderedProfileImageView` was originally a `UIImageView`. Changing this object to a `UIView` and re-linking has resulted in the desired behavior.